# Prove/disprove that $\sum_0^\infty a_nx^n = 0 \rightarrow a_n = 0 \text{ for all }n$ given $|x|<1$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

For $|x|<1$, if the following statement is true, how to prove it? If not, how to disprove it?
$$\sum_0^\infty a_nx^n = 0 \rightarrow a_n = 0 \text{ for all }n$$

In case $x$ takes any real value, it's easy to prove this because the limit ($x\rightarrow\infty)$ of any partial sum (containing nonzero a's) goes to $+/-\infty$.

Comment: Are the $a_n$ bounded?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer in either case

Answer (score 1):

We must have $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}\leq 1$ in order to ensure convergence on the open unit disk $|z|<1$. So we have an analytic function that is everywhere zero on an open disk: this implies $a_n = n!\cdot f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by the Cauchy theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z) = \sum_n a_n z^n$.

Let $R = {1 \over \limsup_n \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$. If $R>0$, then $f$ is analytic on $B(0,R)$ and by differentiating we can show that $a_n = 0$ for all $n$.

if $R=0$, then the series $\sum_n a_n {1 \over 2^n}$ diverges (hence $R>0$, in fact, we have $R \ge 1$).